# How to get a the remote file attributes through FTP using ConnectionKit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, ftp

I need to get the file attributes of a remote file using the [ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) framework.

What I am trying to do is compare the modification date of the file on the server and if it is newer than the local copy then download it. I've got the CKTransferRecord for the transfer but this only gives me the remote file path not that remote files attributes.

What is the best way to get the remote files attributes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had the idea of using CKFTPCommand and running the FTP command "MLST remote/file/path.jpg". I figured out how to create and send the command [connection sendCommand:command] but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the response that the server sends back. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to access the remote file attributes with ConnectionKit?

Comment: Nope. Sure didn't. I reworked some of the project so it wasn't necessary anymore but I really wish I had a solution it would've been much cleaner.